# Stepping into swapcontext() with gdb

Tags: c, linux, unix, gdb, system-calls

I'm doing a project that makes unix system calls. To be specific, my project heavily relies of calls to getcontext(), makecontext(), swapcontext() and setcontext().  I tried to debug my code using gdb. I stepped into the code line by line and examined the control but once a call to swapcontext() is made, it doesn't step into the code anymore. Instead, debugging almost stops there and the rest of the program is run automatically instead of line by line. I guess gdb does not go into context calls? Is there any way to get around this? Is there a debugger that i can use for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setcontext and swapcontext calls change the program's stack, and gdb gets confused. I do not know whether some other debugger can handle it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

gdb steps through one thread and calls this the current thread. Other threads will run as you are doing this. If you set a breakpoint that gets hit in a thread other than the current thread then gdb will change the current thread to that thread. Stepping is now relative to the new current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping with gdb over calls of swapcontext() with 'step' or 'next' does not work because not only the stackpointer changes but also the call returns to a different code line (which is the desired effect of swapcontext()). As gdb puts a breakpoint in the next code line which will not be executed until another swapcontext() returns to this place the execution will not break.

You need to foresee the line to which swapcontext() will return and set a breakpoint there. For a new (unused) context this will be the line you specified as entry function. For used contexts it will probably one of the lines after a swapcontext() there...

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly use GDB's `stepi` command to first step into and then step through the `swapcontext()` function. You must step several dozen times, including a few steps over kernel system calls—I presume to save the floating point state?—and you'll eventually come out in the user thread you're swapping to. It's a tad time-consuming, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

As much as you may not like this answer, the best bet is to step through your code in small chunks *by hand*. Threaded programs don't play very well with debuggers like GDB and Valgrind (at least in my experience) and most bugs can be determined by a careful step-by-step manual analysis of the code.

Comment: `swapcontext` is often used for building threaded programs or programs that essentially simulate multiple threads.

Comment: No, swapcontext is used to build coroutines. Otherwise, gdb can cope just fine with multiple threads.